# Let user change contents of their own (big) file

Tags: php, forms

I've got a web server that accepts a file from the user. It is then processed and the user gets a chance to modify it. The file format is not comfortable for the user to operate with, so my PHP code parses the file and creates a form that would let the user change the file contents. The form is then submitted and a new, modified file is created. In the worst case scenario, the file provided can have up to 160 input fields per row and up to 500 rows which results in 80k of input fields. Even though this sounds horrible, it has to be like that (So all 500 lines have to appear on the same page). The problem arises because of PHP's max_input_vars which is set to 1000. There is no way I can modify it. Therefore I would like to know if there is a way to bypass that restriction or if there is any other, better way of implementing this.

Comment: You could use jQuery to collect each input into an array, encode it as JSON and submit it as a single value.

Comment: if you can't change php, then you'd have to change how the form submits. e.g. use client-side javascript to serialize the big form into a single massive string, and submit it as `form=massive_string_here`, reducing it to one single input field for PHP, which you can then unserialize back into however many zillions of fields there really are.

Comment: Two good suggestions already brought forward and I am sure there are some others. I serialize the data into a string and then pass just the one string.